# Symfony2 redirect all requests

Tags: redirect, symfony

I would like to know if there is a way to redirect all requests if there is a condition.
For example, if I have an entity User with websiteDisabled = true.
As far as I know, you cannot redirect from a service. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create a listener that listens to the `kernel.request` event 
([documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)). In that listener you have access to the request,
and the container so you can do anything you like. During `kernel.request`
Symfony gives you a `GetResponseEvent`.

You can set a `Response` object on this event just as you would return a response 
in a controller. If you do set a response, Symfony will return it and not go
through the normal request --> controller --> response cycle.

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

class UserRedirectListener extends ContainerAware
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            // don't do anything if it's not the master request
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        // for example...
        if ($user->websiteDisabled === false) {
            return;
        }

        // here you could render a template, or create a RedirectResponse
        // or whatever it is
        $response = new Response();

        // as soon as you call GetResponseEvent#setResponse
        // symfony will stop propogation and return the response
        // no other framework code will be executed
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

You will also need to register the event listener in one of your config files, for
example:

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\UserRedirectListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think that it would work with: name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller ?