# Symfony2 routing all url to same controller

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have an application and I want to redirect from my routing.yml (not .htaccess) all the routes to the same path:

```
home:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index }
```

And if a user enter in `/` or in `/section` or even `/sajdfñldasf` always will redirect to home path.

Is it possible to do this with Symfony2 and routing.yml?

Answer (score 8):

You need to define parameter that can handle any value:

```
home:
    path:     /{path}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index, path: "" }
    requirements:
        path: .*
```

Comment: Up vote for setting default value for path. What if user hit */somthing/another/another* ?

Comment: Then `path` param of request will have value __/somthing/another/another__

Comment: I see, because of `path: .*`

Answer (score -1):

Yes

for home

```
home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index }
```

for section

```
section:
    path:     /section
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index }
```

For whatever

```
whatever:
    path:     /whatever
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: yes, but without write all the routes, I want the user write whatever he wants and enter directly to the home.

Comment: so you have to write that logic in your controller

Comment: But if an user enter in '/' or /section/ or 'whatever/ works fine, but If the user enter for example in '/test' will not work

Comment: with path: /{section} and in Defaults the same all works fine :)

Comment: there is one more solution:    You want to create a listener that listens to the kernel.request event (documentation here). In that listener you have access to the request, and the container so you can do anything you like. During kernel.request Symfony gives you a GetResponseEvent.

You can set a Response object on this event just as you would return a response in a controller. If you do set a response, Symfony will return it and not go through the normal request --> controller --> response cycle.

Comment: just check out this may help you...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665988/symfony2-redirect-all-requests